# Limit accepted HTTP response size

Tags: java, http, get, httpclient

I have a code that uses `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient` class in order to download images from the web by url. I want to limit the allowed download size. For example - don't download images that are more than 2MB.

What would be the best way to know the size of the image I want to download before I download it?

Comment: The HTTP response contains the size of the body. But in some cases it might not be present (when, for instance, even the server does not know the size of the file being sent).

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - If I read the content length before reading the body, it means that the body was not yet downloaded. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You can get headers without body by sending a HTTP HEAD request before performing a HTTP GET.

So, you send a HEAD request, get the body size by parsing the HEAD response (which is what you would get with a GET request, except that there is no body, only headers) and decide whether to perform the GET request to download the file or not.